# How to stop excessive 206 Partial Content requests on mp4 files on IIS10

Tags: iis-10

I am running IIS10 on Windows 2019, and a user periodically will upload media such as MOV and MP4. Until recently, all such files generated either a 200 or 206 status code once or maybe a couple times if the requester skipped beyond the buffered video. This continues to be the case for the older files.

A new file, also MP4 format, is behaving differently and I don't know why. It generates a new 206 status code request on inconsistent but rapid timing, averaging around 20 per second. This behavior is visible in Chrome networking and in the log. I'm noticing a roughly 14% increase in CPU usage from the application pool which correlates strongly with these calls.

Since it's only the newest file doing it, logic tells me it's something to do with how the file was exported not playing nice with at least Chrome versions 120 and 121 on Windows, but I have limited ability to affect how people export their files or which browsers they use. I'm going to pursue that with the specific user this time but I would like to find a general solution to prevent this in the future.

I already have dynamic IP restrictions set to 25 per 300ms but this generally runs just under that.

Is there a configuration in IIS10 that I can make to encourage browsers to buffer normally rather than this heavy Partial Content/206 traffic?

[image: screenshot of Chrome showing 206 status requests for the same file in 2-digit millisecond increments]

EDIT: The suggested solution [IIS application request routing changes 206 partial content to 200](https://serverfault.com/questions/757930/iis-application-request-routing-changes-206-partial-content-to-200) did not resolve the issue, though it did affect it. This question's solution converted 206 calls to 200 calls, which slightly reduced the frequency of the calls, shifting from roughly 20-80ms intervals to 80-170ms intervals. This is an improvement but doesn't solve the problem.

[image: screenshot of Chrome showing 200 status requests after attempting the solution from another question]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS application request routing changes 206 partial content to 200](https://serverfault.com/questions/757930/iis-application-request-routing-changes-206-partial-content-to-200)

Comment: Definitely looks promising. I'll read up on it more and see if it works. I didn't find that when I did my pre-post search. Thanks!

Comment: I attempted that and related values for Accept-Ranges, but the result didn't solve the problem. It did have an effect (changing to 200 status and increasing time intervals slightly), but no setting solved the issue.